# Getting only new column data from users

Tags: 2007, infopath, custom-list

I have an existing custom list in which I just added a drop-down required column. For new items, that column is required, but I want to gather only that column data from users for existing items without modifying other columns. Can it be possible via a custom InfoPath form? My current environment is MOSS 2007. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Ashish, your custom list forms are already customized through InfoPath?

Comment: No. I have not used InfoPath.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you want a column be required in edit form but optional in new form?

make a custom form template control and set contenttype editformtemplatename and newformtemplatename

[ref this](http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=987)

Comment: We do not support customization in existing environment. The column will be required column in new and existing forms. I want to get this functionality via OOTB controls and methods. Re-iterating, I want to get the new column data from users for existing items.

Comment: does SPD allowed? create a new form page by SPD, then custom it, remove other columns?

Answer (score 0):

**In SharePoint 2010:**

1. Customize forms in InfoPath and put only DropDownList column in
   the form!
2. List Settings -> Form Settings -> There is an option to use default
   forms or InfoPath form, make it to use default forms!
3. Add a Link to InfoPath form with each ListItem using Calculated
   Column!

But I don't know if this is possible in SharePoint 2007, can you confirm if there is Form Settings option in List Settings?